# How can I access specific columns of updated rows of on a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I'm working on a C# application and using the DataGridView component. My datagrid is connected to my database and loads a single data table. The user fills empty fields and saves the changes on the DataGridView and also database. The question is that I need to use a specific column's index that the user filled.

This is the code that creates the datagrid:

```
void gridDoldur()
{
    try
    {
        string query = "SELECT DersId FROM Dersler WHERE DersAd= @dersad";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SEFA-PC;Initial Catalog=proje;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        comd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dersad", dersBox.SelectedItem);

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dre;              // dersin adından id'si çekildi
        dre = comd.ExecuteReader();
        dre.Read();
        int dersId = dre.GetInt32(0);  

        dt.Clear();
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Notlar WHERE DersId=" + dersId, conn);

        sda.Fill(dt);
        notGrid.DataSource = dt;
        notGrid.Visible = true;
        kaydetButton.Visible = true;
        notGrid.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        notGrid.Columns[8].Visible = false;
        notGrid.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
        notGrid.Columns[7].ReadOnly = true;

        sBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
        conn.Close();
}
```

And this is how my grid looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLagd.jpg

I need to access elements of edited rows.

Comment: It sounds like you have two questions: [1] how to know what rows have been changed, [2] how to access a specific column on a row. From the code you've written (e.g. `notGrid.Columns[0]`) it looks like you know the answer to [2]. Have you tried searching for [1]?

Comment: Yes, I need to know which rows has been edited, and use all that rows' specific column as a parameter for a method. I searched for it, but  couldn't find what I am actually looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spin over the rows on the DataTable and check their [DataRowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine if they have changed.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
    {
        var infoINeed = (int) row["SomeInformation"];
        var infoByColumnIndex = row[3].ToString();
        // Do stuff
    }
}

dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Once you are finished with your processing, you'll want to be sure to call [`AcceptChanges()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx). This will change the `RowState` on `DataRowState.Modified` rows to `DataRowState.Unchanged`.

Comment: It doesnt work yet, I implemented your solution into my code, but when I set a breakpoint and run it step by step, " if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)" this if always returns 0. what could be the possible mistake here ?

Comment: You usually have to "finish" editing the context of the cell first.  I thought that happened when you leave a cell (press enter, tab, click on another cell), but let's say the user clicks save while still typing in a cell. You can call `DataGridView1.EndEdit()` to "finish" those changes. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13139877/945456). That could be your issue.

Comment: I found that the problem about the behaviour of sda.update(dt) method and I fixed it. Also, I have a question to you, if you dont bother. How can you fix your code above, if I want to access the updated columns and cell values of the row?

Comment: You call use `row["SomeInformation", DataRowVersion.Original]` to see the original value and compare it with `row["SomeInformation"]` to see if anything had changed. When you call `AcceptChanges` that information goes away though. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2756965/945456

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for your purposes since it will trigger every time any cell in a row is changed, however you can get a general idea from it hopefully.  You can easily grab the row index using the DataGridView's CellValueChanged event handler.  The idea here would be to note which rows have had a change in this method, like so:

```
private List<int> editedRows = new List<int>;

private void myDGV_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (!this.editedRows.Contains(e.RowIndex))
  {
     editedRows.Add(e.RowIndex);
  }
}
```

With this idea, you could call your method something like this:

```
foreach (int row in this.editedRows)
{
  this.MyMethod((int)myDGV[row, 0].Value, (int)myDGV[row, 1].Value, (int)myDGV[row, 2].Value, ...);
}
```

Or:

```
foreach (int row in this.editedRows)
{
  DataGridViewRow r = myDGV.Rows[row];
  this.MyMethod((int)r.Cells[0].Value, (int)r.Cells[1].Value, (int)r.Cells[2].Value, ...);
}
```

Note: Remember to cast the cell value to your data type (I assumed int based on the screenshot).

I did't see the context of your method anywhere, so hopefully this gives you a general idea of where to go next.

Edit: I would go with Jeff's answer.  It gets the same idea across without the need of manually storing a list of updated rows.